# Android Realm initial setup

Tags: android, installation, realm

I would like to start using Realm for android but i having problem setting it up.  i follow the instructions located at https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#getting-started  but still doesnt work.
here is my gradle(project)
[image]

here is my gradle (app)
[image]

[image]

i create a class and extend RealmObject, android studio complains and give me message "Cannot revolve symbol Realmobject". here is a snaphot of my class
[image]

my gradle are syncing up fine and there is no error while syncing but for some reason i am not able to start coding Realm object. can someone help me and tell me what i am doing wrong?  im using android studio 3.1.3

Comment: Have your gradle sync went normal? Please, check if there was an error during sync. Also, the tutorial you mentioned only requires classpath and apply plugin, try removing the rest of your additions.

Comment: yes, gradle sync went normal. no error. also i removed the rest of the additions and nothing. i added the additions because it was not working with classpath and plugin.  any ideas?

Comment: Realm 5+ needs Android-Adapters 3+, and you should follow the guide https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#how-do-i-customize-dependecies-defined-by-the-realm-gradle-plugin

Comment: hi EpicPandaForce, i changed adapter to 3+ and also follow guide. it is still not working. gradle compiles but i cannot use realm objects

Comment: i found the problem. i need to add apply plugin: 'realm-android'
 to gradle(feature) file as well

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that apply plugin: 'realm-android'
also needs to be added to gradle(feature) file